# How Can I run PM2 with Angular-Cli? - Angular2

Tags: nginx, angular, digital-ocean, pm2

How can I run:
`ng serve --prod` with pm2?

ng serve from angular-cli, Angular2. I'm running on DigitalOcean.

I have tried to test with `http-server -p 4200 -d false` in the dist/ folder after `ng build --prod`

When I request from the domain https://www.unibookkh.com/, i got 404 error: (I've already setup nginx to listen to port 4200.

[image]

I test with http-server because I think I maybe can run pm2 through this command 
`pm2 start my_app_process.json` where

**my_app_process.json**

```
{
    "apps": [
        {
            "name": "angular",
            "cwd": "~/angular2",
            "args": "-p 4200 -d false",
            "script": "/usr/bin/http-server"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any better ideas of how to get it working with PM2?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This command would work as expected:

after I run

`ng build --prod`

then run the following command in the dist/ folder

`pm2 start /usr/bin/http-server -- -p 8080 -d false`

### Update

I have found a better solution:
`which ng`
then it will print /usr/bin/ng
then type this

`pm2 start /usr/bin/ng -- serve --prod`

Comment: I tried your method to run my application and have an error in pm2 log file.

`SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: You can also do `pm2 start $(which ng)`

Comment: It works perfectly but uses lots of memory (I know this is not a problem but a simple application  less than 100 lines uses more than 400mb). of course this is a problem of angular app. I think the best way is build app for production and make a simple sh file and run it

Comment: I tried that, it shows the instance status started, but it's not serving

Answer (score 15):

But, if you need ng serve for dev in preprod env, you can create a start.sh at root of your project

```
#!/bin/bash
ng serve --host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --port xxxx
```

And use pm2 like that :

```
pm2 start start.sh --name my-pretty-dev-app-run-on-preprod
```

;)

Comment: @Julien Moulin, is there any other way then .sh file? using exisitng .json file can we do this?

Comment: Your answer saved lot of time.

Answer (score 7):

With PM2 recent version

```
pm2 ecosystem
```

than update

> ecosystem.config.js as follows

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: 'demoapp',
    script: 'node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng',
    args: 'serve --host [yourip] --disable-host-check',
    instances: 1,
    autorestart: true,
    watch: false,
    max_memory_restart: '1G',
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: 'development'
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: 'production'
    }
  }],

  deploy : {
  }
};
```

finally

> pm2 start & pm2 save

Comment: great answer, deserves more upvotes - works on latest pm2 version - although see the tweak I had to make to this in my answer

Comment: I have compeletely different content, so should I delet them all and put your code there? Should I modify app name or [your ip]? How?

Comment: @user3486308 Yes you need to update the [app name] and [IP], Most important are script and args you can add these in your current config.

if any issue please share config file via pastebin.

Answer (score 1):

The following, for example, worked for me from the angular project:
`pm2 start "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0"`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. The key difference here between this answer and the other answers is that I had to use the `cwd` option since I was running pm2 from a root directory:

```
// pm2 start
// https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/guide/ecosystem-file
// https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/reference/ecosystem-file

module.exports = {
  apps: [{
    name: 'fe',
    script: 'node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng',
    args: 'serve -o',
    cwd: 'biblical-hebrew-fe',
    max_restarts: 5,
    min_uptime: 3000,
    exec_mode: 'fork',
    instances: 1, // default
    autorestart: true, // default
    watch: false, // default
    max_memory_restart: '1G', // default
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: 'development'
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: 'production'
    }
  }],

  deploy: {
    production: {
      user: 'node',
      host: '212.83.163.1',
      ref: 'origin/master',
      repo: 'git@github.com:repo.git',
      path: '/var/www/production',
      'post-deploy': 'npm install && pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js --env production'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

ng is a node module after all.

```
apps:
- name: ngserve
  script: 'node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng'
  args: 'serve --progress=false --live-reload=false --disable-host-check=true'
  watch: false
  log_date_format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm
  merge_logs: true
  out_file: "/dev/null"
  error_file: "/dev/null"
```

Answer (score -2):

If you just want to serve static files, a new command has landed in pm2:

$ pm2 expose [path] [port]

Comment: This answer doesn't really have anything to do with how to serve an angular2 app with pm2