# How can I configure PM2 for angular-cli app

Tags: angular, angular-cli, pm2

Referring to this:
[How Can I run PM2 with Angular-Cli? - Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314654/how-can-i-run-pm2-with-angular-cli-angular2/39315665)

Is it possible to run pm2 configuration with angular-cli?

Something like this - 
pm2.json:

```
{
"apps": [{
    "name": "my-app",
    "script": "./usr/bin/ng serve",
    "instances": "1",
    "error_file"      : "err.log",
    "out_file"        : "out.log",
    "merge_logs"      : true,
    "log_date_format" : "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z",
    "env": {
      "NODE_ENV": "development"
    },
    "env_production" : {
      "NODE_ENV": "production"
    }
}]
```

}

From command line this command works:
**pm2 start /usr/bin/ng -- serve --prod**

but this doesn't:
**pm2 start pm2.json**

Comment: This is very interesting question. I am facing this issue!

Comment: I have decided not to use pm2 with angular front application. Now I used it for backend.

Comment: Check out my answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53059613/4082865