# How to start/serve angular using PM2 process?

Tags: angular, npm, pm2

My `package.json` has following scripts -

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --configuration=dev",
    "build": "ng build --prod --progress",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

And I have uploaded the `dist` folder that was created on the server and it had an `index.html` that I want to serve. Just wondering as how to start it using PM2.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314654/how-can-i-run-pm2-with-angular-cli-angular2

Comment: I am using nginx, so don't think http server should be really required. Please correct me if otherwise.